# Facing error when importing virtual product in magento2

Tags: magento2, import-products, virtual-products

I want to import virtual product when i was importing catalog_product.csv it's giving me below error:

> 1.Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.
>
> 2.Options for downloadable products not found in row(s): 1